# Find text in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following text.
[Account].&[1]
I want to retrieve only Account from this string. I written regular expression like this.

```
var rexp =  /\[[a-z][A-Z]\]/g;
var matchStr = id.match(rexp);
```

But it is not working. Is there any thing wrong in this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\[[a-z][A-Z]\]/` matches exactly *one* lowercase char (`a-z`) followed by *one* uppercase char (`A-Z`). Instead, consider `/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/` which evaluates to "one or more lower- or uppercase chars."

The `i` flag (case-insensitive) can do the same as `[a-z][A-Z]`: `/\[[a-z]+\]/gi`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it to this: `\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/g`.

In your current regular expression you are expecting to match a lower case string followed by an upper case string. Since the string you want to match starts with an upper case letter followed by more lower case letters then your regular expression will not work.

The regex I proposed should match any string made up from one or more (`+` operator) letters (both lower and upper case `[a-zA-Z]`) which resides within the square brackets `[` and `]`.